# Best approach for MySQL query depending on user

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm building an app where users are going to edit records on a table and make comments.

The table has a ton of columns but for this post the important ones are:

Sold by
Manager 
Region

There's 4 account types:

Sales rep: they can only view records where the column sold by is their name.

Manager: they can only view records where the column sold by is their name and the manger column is there name.

Regional manager: they can only view records where the column sold by is their name and where region is their region.

Admin: they can view everything

My issue is making the proper query. I was going to have multiple pages and just have a query for each account but I'm sure there's a better way?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have three tables;

1. User Roles (I guess you already have it)
2. Permissions
3. User Permissions (Link-Table)

You can create a CRUD structure to assign Permissions to user. If you want to make it more complex, you can create permission groups.

Once you have permissions assigned to users than you can create your queries by first checking the permission from user_permissions table based on user role which you will be keeping in the session(hopefully).

Comment: User roles: user, manager, regional manager | what about the other tables?

Comment: manager, sales rep, admin, regional manager they are all user roles. view, edit, delete these are permissions . For example. For your first requirement. You need to check whether sales rep can view records, if yes, then create query to view records and in WHERE clause put his own id = sales_by thats it